# How to call fadeOut() after load()

Tags: jquery, load, fadeout

```
$('#page_name').load(url + ' #page_name') // url - some container. ex - #container
$('#page_name').delay(300).fadeIn(1000)
```

and nothing :(

Trying live(), but nothing comes out

Comment: what is your url? what response are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback function for load.

```
$('#page_name').load(url + ' #page_name', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

I don't think you can use .delay in this context.

> The .delay() method is best for
>   delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects.

Comment: I removed the delay() but ... ((

Answer (score 0):

Fade the content in from within `$.load`'s success callback:

```
$('#page_name').load(url + ' #page_name', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(1000)
});
```

Comment: i think it is safe to take out the delay